Showing trading chart in web view in Jetpackcompose
in my Jetpackcompose project I have a webView which I need to show a trading chart but it white page
this is how I Impleament my wevView in jetpackCompose
AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            WebView(context).apply {
                webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
                settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
                loadUrl("https://p.rabex.ir/fa/trade/chart/uni/BTCUSDT")
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) 

